# getSymbols downloading data for multiple symbols and export adjusting prices to CSV file

Tags: r, stock, quantmod

quantmode newbie here,

My end goal is to have a CSV file including monthly stock prices, I've downloaded the data using getSymbols using this code:

```
Symbols <- c("DIS", "TSLA","ATVI", "MSFT", "FB", "ABT","AAPL","AMZN",
             "BAC","NFLX","ADBE","WMT","SRE","T","MS")

Data <- new.env()
getSymbols(c("^GSPC",Symbols),from="2015-01-01",to="2020-12-01"
           ,periodicity="monthly",
             env=Data)
```

the line above works fine, now I need to create a data frame that only includes the adjusted prices for all the symbols with a data column ofc,

any help, please? :)

Desired output would be something similar to this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIUWT.png)

Comment: Sorry I had a typo, I need the date column as well

Comment: Can you add a minimal desired output example?

Comment: I just uploaded an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another straightforward way to get your monthly data:

```
tickers <- c('AMZN','FB','GOOG','AAPL')
getSymbols(tickers,periodicity="monthly")
head(do.call("merge.xts",c(lapply(mget(tickers),"[",,6),all=FALSE)),3)

           AMZN.Adjusted FB.Adjusted GOOG.Adjusted AAPL.Adjusted
2012-06-01        228.35       31.10      288.9519      17.96558
2012-07-01        233.30       21.71      315.3032      18.78880
2012-08-01        248.27       18.06      341.2658      20.46477
```

Note the logical argument `all = FALSE` is the equivalent of an `inner`join and  you get data when **all** of your stocks have prices. `all = TRUE` fills data which is not available with `NA`s (`outer`join).
To write the file you can use:

```
write.zoo(monthlyPrices,file = 'filename.csv',sep=',',quote=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

First get your data from the environment:

```
require(quantmod)
# your code
dat <- mget(ls(Data), env=Data)
```

Then draw the data from the Objects:

```
newdat <- as.data.frame(sapply( names(dat), function(x) coredata(dat[[x]])[,1] ))
```

Note that this takes the Opening values (see: dat[[x]])[,**1**]), the Objects have more, e.g.:

```
names(dat[["AAPL"]])
[1] "AAPL.Open"     "AAPL.High"     "AAPL.Low"      "AAPL.Close"
[5] "AAPL.Volume"   "AAPL.Adjusted"
```

Last, get the dates (assumes symmetric dates for all symbols):

```
rownames(newdat) <- index(dat[["AAPL"]])
# OR, more universal, by extracting from the complete list:
rownames(newdat) <-
    as.data.frame( sapply( names(dat), function(x) as.character(index(dat[[x]])) ) )[,1]
```

```
head(newdat, 3)
              AAPL   ABT  ADBE   AMZN  ATVI   BAC    DIS    FB    GSPC    MS
2015-01-01 27.8475 45.25 72.70 312.58 20.24 17.99  94.91 78.58 2058.90 39.05
2015-02-01 29.5125 44.93 70.44 350.05 20.90 15.27  91.30 76.11 1996.67 33.96
2015-03-01 32.3125 47.34 79.14 380.85 23.32 15.79 104.35 79.00 2105.23 35.64
            MSFT     NFLX    SRE     T   TSLA   WMT
2015-01-01 46.66 49.15143 111.78 33.59 44.574 86.27
2015-02-01 40.59 62.84286 112.38 33.31 40.794 84.79
2015-03-01 43.67 67.71429 108.20 34.56 40.540 83.93
```

Writing the csv:

```
write.csv(newdat, "file.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, everything went smooth, only one thing I got differently, I used the same line you wrote for rownames, instead of getting dates I got a column starting with 16436, 16467, 16495 etc etc, is there anything I could do about that?

Comment: Yep, sorry, already adjusted that in my answer. I copied the wrong line from my code. Forgot the `as.data.frame` in the second step where you create the newdat Object.

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to accept/vote whenever you like!